# Why a 200 MB text file overloads 4gB ram

Tags: memory, c++, textfiles

I wrote a simple program in c++ that does some calculations, outputs a number to a textfile, and repeats. Several million times. The final text file was around 215 megabytes, yet when I opened it, gedit took over 5 minutes to open all of it, and I went over my 4 Gb of ram and into the linux swap. Why does this happen when the original file size is only 200 MB?

Comment: `gedit` is the one using up high amounts of memory, not your own program, right?

Comment: Correct. The program when executed took up under 20 Mb but slowly rose by about .1 Mb every minute.

Comment: Run gedit from valgrind. This will tell you wether there are memory leaks present in your version of gedit.
On my system (Ubuntu 12.04.4) this is the case. So I have to quit all instances of gedit from time to time to free all the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching around on Google, `gedit` seems to handle large files very badly

- http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-289999.html
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/156201

I would try opening the files in something like `less`

`vim` by default does not behave as well as I thought it did on large files, if you want to use `vim` you should use something like http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506

Comment: Well, I just tried opening the file in gvim, and the ram usage only increased by about 230 MB. It is funny, I opened a program written in c a while ago that was about 100 mb, but gedit didn't react so severly. Thanks.

Comment: And to answer the other part of your question, I really do not know *why* gedit uses that much memory -- may be partly due to bad programming, or a bug.  I don't see any reason why it should.  If you want the least memory intensive way to view a huge file, I think `less` is the only way to go, from my digging ( you can't *edit* it in that case, though )

Comment: +1 for less! I once had to open a 37.1 GiB file and only less worked!

Comment: If editing text in the command line gives you the shudders, consider [Geany](https://www.geany.org). It is the one editor that worked in my testing with > 1 GiB files. Very lightweight.